# What technique is used for the opening of this Soundgarden song?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

The song Loud Love by Soundgarden opens with several single notes on the guitar.  They sound almost like bowed notes on a cello.

I'm not sure if maybe Kim Thayil is working the volume knob, or if this is accomplished with a volume pedal, or even more effects.

Does anyone know?

Video above for reference.

Comment: I'm only hearing the volume rise on the first note. The rest sounds to me like hammer-on, at levels high enough for feedback to keep the sustain. [Pure guesswork, so can't post an answer]

Comment: Wikipedia says feedback: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loud_Love http://web.stargate.net/soundgarden/articles/gschool_5-94.shtml

Comment: @user1079505 excellent find.  Fashion that into an answer and the cred is yours.

Comment: Not sure if the question is on topic and @Aaron wants to dv answers to off-topic questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't agree that this sounds anything like bowed cello notes, but it does sound a lot like an [EBow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBow). That's a device which generates feedback similar to what you can get by having the amp vibrate the guitar, but without the loudspeaker – instead, it directly vibrates the strings magnetically.

However, as per [the article that Wikipedia and user1079505 linked to](http://web.stargate.net/soundgarden/articles/gschool_5-94.shtml), Kim Thayil actually used amp feedback, not an EBow. That requires cranking the amp *very loud* (in particular, high gain) and standing close to it with the guitar. Even then it's quite difficult to control which notes / partials actually get sustained. So if you want to play this intro reliably, I would anyway recommend trying an EBow.

In addition to feedback, the guitar has a lot of distortion and a lot of reverb on it.